# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" in cursor in Android

Tags: java, android, database, cursor

I looked at simmiliar questions but i didn't find an answer.

I get an error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

It shows on line:

```
    Place place = new Place(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4), cursor.getInt(5));
```

It's my code:

```
    Place getMyPlace(String sql, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PLACES, new String[] {PLACES_COLUMN_ID, PLACES_COLUMN_NAME,
                PLACES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION}, PLACES_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Place place = new Place(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4), cursor.getInt(5));
        return place;
    }
```

It's a constructor from class Place:

```
public Place(int id, String placeName, String placeDescription, double latidute, double longtidute, int visited){
    this._id = id;
    this._placeName = placeName;
    this._placeDescription = placeDescription;
    this._latidute = latidute;
    this._longtidute = longtidute;
    this._visited = visited;
}
```

And method from acticity:

```
public void getPlace(int id){
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    String sql ="SELECT Name, Description FROM Places WHERE _id=?" ;
    Place myPlace = dbHelper.getMyPlace(sql, id); 
}
```

Do somebody know what may be wrong?

Comment: please put logcat of error

Comment: it seems your last parameter (visited) doesn't have any value. try to debug your code and be sure that visited is not null in your db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your db.query

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PLACES, new String[] {PLACES_COLUMN_ID, 
            PLACES_COLUMN_NAME, PLACES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION}, PLACES_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

to this

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PLACES, null, PLACES_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: by using new String[] {PLACES_COLUMN_ID, PLACES_COLUMN_NAME, PLACES_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION}, you are get only 3 column from db but you are put column in your bean class.

Answer (score 1):

It´s possible that there is a value inside the database which is empty here:

```
  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))
```

This is the first parameter of Your Place Object. You have to be sure, that this is a number, You can do it like this:

```
  int numberYouNeed = 0;
  String yourString = cursor.getString(0);

  if(yourString!=null&&!yourString.equals("")){
  numberYouNeed = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
  }

  Place place = new Place(numberYouNeed, cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4), cursor.getInt(5))
```